# Nexus 10 not booting, showing Google and lock icon when turned on

Tags: boot, samsung-nexus-10

This is odd. My Nexus 10 has been working great a quite a while now, but now, suddenly, when I turn it on, its quickly shows a Google title in the middle, and a lock icon at the bottom (in landscape mode only). The lock looks like a padlock and it looks open (not fully closed). Nothing happens when I wait. I can turn the tablet off by holding the power button for about 5 seconds. The tablet then stays off, until I press the power button for about 1 second. "Google" and the open padlock icon then reappears.
I've image-googled for anything about not booting and lock icons and whatnot, but I can't find anything that resembles this.
I've had an ipod touch years back and after my toddler tried to log in a few times, I lost access to it, and lost all my data. This made me not wanting to try Apple again. I seriously hope I'm not dealing with something like this here now again...

Comment: You seem to have got an unlocked bootloader. How, I don't know (I don't use nexus devices) but all your personal data is probably gone (wiped for security reasons) try reflashing a stock  ROM

Answer (score 0):

So if the lock icon was `closed` before and just `opened` somehow, you should find out what happens.

Now the lock is `opened`, so your `boot-loader` is opened. Have you opened it?

There are BL-unlocking apps available but all of them need root permission so I think this is not the cause. But I'm sure the device did not open its BL.

> I lost access to it, and lost all my data. This made me not wanting to try Apple again. I seriously hope I'm not dealing with something like this here now again...

On the Nexus devices if you open the device's Bootloader all data will be deleted. It's a security concern. The Android documentation doesn't provide a lot of elaboration, stating simply:

> The procedure must be confirmed on-screen, and deletes the user data
>   for privacy reasons.

Once the bootloader is unlocked, the rooting process is quite easy so all of the information on `/data` essentially becomes accessible. This could be emails, contact information, or many other pieces of personal information that you likely don't want in the wrong hands. Therefore, it makes sense to wipe all of this data during the unlocking procedure.

TL;DR: If the device `bootloader` was opened somehow, all of your data will be gone.

Comment: First, thanks for taking the effort to help. I never knew about unlocked icon. What's possible is that my 7 year old, after watching "instructional" videos on youtube, obsessed with trying to run "Windows 10" on the tablet, is that he ended up running something that "unlocked" the boot loader, which apparently causes the erasing of all data. I don't know if that is accurate. He assured me that he didn't download an apk and sideloaded anything. I told him off about side loading before. Somehow he did something that caused the tablet to no longer boot.

Comment: If the data is gone, that's ok at this point. I would love for this tablet to somehow fully boot again. Since it refuses to boot, I've since been trying to reload firmware on it. I can see CM13 is available for instance. The problems now is for adb to recognize the tablet when plugging it in when activating the power+volume_up menu (which shows: "Downloading... Do not turn off target !!"). I was hoping to flash an img file using fastboot. I'm doing this on Linux (I do not have Windows handy). I've adjusted udev and adb_usb.ini, to no avail. "adb devices" comes up empty every time.

Comment: lsusb:<br>
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (Download mode)<br>
/etc/udev/rules.d/51-nexus.rules:<br>
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:ff420?:*", MODE="0666"<br>